# FloatBarriers create spaces before next text

Tags: spacing, floats

I use FloatBarriers to keep pictures at the place I want them to be. Unfortunately the FloatBarriers seem to create the red underlined space before the next text section.
How can I avoid this?

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Beispiel Fristentransformation}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{/home/.../Beispiel1.jpg}
\caption*{Quelle: Eigene Darstellung}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
Je größer das Ungleichgewicht....
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

`\FloatBarrier` needs to work in vertical mode so issues `\par` so it is as if you had a blank line at that position so you see a paragraph indent in the following text.

Using a float followed immediately by `\FloatBarrier` to stop floats floating is perhaps an unnatural choice, it might be better to use a non-floating figure such as using `[H]` from the float package so the image does not float, and you would not need `\FloatBarrier`.

Note, `\begin{figure}[!h]` is an odd choice if you need to keep figures close to the text as it makes gong to the end of the document quite likely as it means not at top of page or bottom of page or on a page of its own. which gives latex almost no chance to set it anywhere. (latex usually changes it to `[ht]` to give at least some possibilities to position the image)

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, can you give me an example how I should include my figure?

Comment: Changing the code to:

Comment: @MaximilianJung I would guess changing `[!h]` to `[H]` including the `float` package and deleting `\FloatBarrier` (you could also simply put `\noindent` in front of the text so it doesn't indent the text, but that's covering the symptom not solving the issue (it is the easiest though:-)

Comment: I changed it to [H] and removed the \FloatBarrier, but this didnt change the red underlined spaces. Usind \noindent worked